# How to safely contribute answers?

Tags: support, answers, protected-questions

Recently, a question I answered was "protected" because it was attracting spam and low grade activity. I'm older and don't use the Internet that much so I may be a bit ignorant regarding these subjects. The content was solid; I used a G.M.s name and the initials of a major city. Did this attract spam?

Suggestions and information are appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Are you referring to [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/442/7297)? Yes, I protected that question because I'm not sure that question needs more answers. Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, focused on getting answers to questions, and not a discussion forum where everybody can chime in and post their opinion. I now see that this isn't covered in the list of reasons mentioned in the notice:

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users.

"Low quality" isn't in that list, but it could very well be. In any case, your *answer* isn't attracting low quality activity; it's low quality in itself. Let me explain why:

The problem with your answer (and all others you've posted) is that they're hard to read due to the lack of capitals, improper punctuation (`/`), not having paragraphs etc. This isn't an Internet skill, or unfamiliarity with Stack Exchange; it's about general writing skills. Contrary to what you might see on other places on the Internet, proper grammar and formatting are very much appreciated here.

Other users might help you by [editing](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) your answers (like I did to this question), but *you* are first and foremost responsible for the content of your posts.

**edit:** it seems [somebody jumped on the bandwagon](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8847).